# How to simulate non-invasive blood glucometer in Proteus?

Tags: sensor, simulation, infrared, photodiode, proteus

I'm working on a project in which I'm trying to create a non-invasive blood glucometer using NIR light and a photodiode.

The glucose level is determined by the amount of light absorbed by the blood, is the idea I have.

I'd like to simulate it in Proteus; is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Absolutely you can.  Develop an electrical analogue model of the light/plasma glucose response and use that in Proteus.  It might require some R&D if you don't have a good understanding of the interface.

Comment: Obviously Proteus doesn't know anything about blood glucose and never will, but you can most likely simulate the photodiode with a current source. Measure the current you get for a specific amount of blood glucose, and add a current source for that amount of current.